# What can be done to get the visa in the required time?

Tags: visa-refusals, tourist-visas, turkey

My tourist visa to Turkey was refused, on 25th Feb, thanks to the rep here who mismanaged my case. All my documents said 'paid by my brother in UK' while he insisited i write 'i will be taking care of the expenditures myself' and i think that was enough to confuse everything up. Now, our trip was planned 8 months ago and everything has been paid for for the 29th of March. What can i do to get the visa and go visit Turkey on the abovesaid date?

Comment: Out of interest, why did you go along with what the rep said if you were uncomfortable with what he wanted you to do? What reason was given for the refusal? Are you sure the rep even submitted an application?

Comment: What nationality are you ? Many nationalities can purchase a visa at the airport on entry. UK nationals £20. There was word this would be phased out in favour of the on line applications but you can still currently buy at the airport in Turkey. I don't know however what will happen now that you have been refused.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.